# Assembly-CSharp (incompatible)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity

Tengo este error y aún no logro solucionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código unas palabras reservadas no tienen los colores que deberían tener; Visual Studio 2019 está configurado como editor de scripts externo en Unity, pero no soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has intentado agregar nuevamente el proyecto?
Da clic derecho en tu solución, busca la opción **Add** => **Existing Project**, entonces agregas el archivo con extensión *.csproj* que debería encontrarse en el path del proyecto.

Comment: María muchas gracias, funcionó pero antes me tocó instalar versiones anteriores porque no me daba la opción. Gracias!!

Comment: Entiendo. Excelente que encontraras la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo problema, en mi caso solo le di click derecho a "Assembly-CSharp (incompatible)" y le di en reload para que lo volviese a cargar.
El problema se me solucionó.